# Does Jboss 4.2.3.GA support JDK 1.4.2?

Tags: java, jboss, jdk1.4

I'm migrating my apps from WebSphere to JBoss. I would like to know if JBoss 4.2.3 GA supports JDK 1.4.2.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, JDK 1.5 is required for JBoss 4.2 and upwards.

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossVsJavaJDKVersionMatrix

If you're stuck on Java 1.4, then JBossAS 4.0.x is the best you can do. If you're *not* stuck on Java 1.4, then you *really* need to upgrade to 1.6 - even 1.5 has reached end-of-life by now.